# Persistently Installing a Key for App-Exclusive Use via Android Keystore System

Tags: android, android-keystore

I am working on  deployment scenario where my Android application is pre-installed on devices that will not have internet access. For security purposes, I want to manually install a cryptographic key onto these devices. This key should be persistently stored and made accessible only to my application, utilizing the Android Keystore system.

Is it possible to manually install a cryptographic key into the Android Keystore system in a way that it is persistent across device reboots and accessible only by a specific application?

Thanks in advance